# GWT, modifying code that uses InputStreamReader and java.net.URL class to send a HashMap or other object through Post?

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, rpc

I'm fairly new to GWT and have been trying to piece together things to be able to have a separate GWT app interact with a spring app. I have been able to get this working where I have a class that extends `RemoteServiceServlet` and it is now able to successfully do a GET request to my spring app and get the response. While this is a good starting point, I'd like to figure out how to now be able to send an actual object from GWT (such as just a HashMap for testing) to Spring through a POST method.

I would appreciate any advice on this to point me in the right direction, I don't know much about doing this and have been looking at tutorials but I keep getting a bit confused and am not quite sure how to try to implement this. On this note, in the code below I am not quite sure even at what point the call is actually being made to the spring app, is it when the `new URL` is created ?

Below is an example of the code that I am using to do the GET request from GWT:

```
private String getSpringResponse(String message) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-mysql/test/test/"+message+"/");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
                .openStream()));

        while(reader.ready()){
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create POST requests via URLConnection: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html

If your Spring server replies with JSON you can use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to map to your classes, or if it returns XML you can [use JAXB](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html).

There is also possibility to talk to Spring server directly from GWT via [cross-site requests](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html). In this case Spring server should be returning JSON.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just learned about the JSON return for cross site requests but I already have javascript / spring code that is not using JSON so I would prefer an approach where I can avoid re-writing. As far as the POST method for URL Connection, do you know if I can send objects over it (such as even just a basic HashMap)? Thanks for your advice

Comment: You have to serialize objects. This is what JSON or XML is used for. What is your Spring server accepting?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to go with a pure GWT stack (i.e. gwt-dispatch, gin, and guice.) For this approach take a look at the gwt-platform project, clean gwt client/server and DI framework all rolled into one.

If you do not have the luxury to change the technology stack and your server is already built or you're more comfortable with the spring DI framework. You can integrate the spring servlets by taking an approach similar to the spring4gwt project.

With [spring4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt) it seems all you need to do is identify the spring service you want to integrate into your GWT client and define the standard RemoteService classes on the client.

The latest versions of GWT will automatically handle serialization for all classes marked Serializable (includes HashMap) or IsSerializable (for custom data classes.) See [gwt serialization docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm definitely pretty set on staying with Spring for server-side, I have heard of spring4gwt so I will look into that, I honestly seem to have trouble understanding some of this stuff as far as communication between gwt and spring but I suppose its just my newness to it

Comment: also check out [gwt-platform's simple spring sample](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/#hg%2Fgwtp-samples%2Fgwtp-sample-basic-spring)